# Visualization/Drawing Request of a line L intersecting all three coordinate planes Oxy, Oyz, and Ozx

Tags: multivariable-calculus, visualization

I'm not sure how to draw a line that intersects all three coordinate planes. I'm suspicious that such a line doesn't exist. How do we prove its existence? I guess we should try draw a picture. I beg for a picture.

Comment: Just draw a line through the origin...

Comment: the point common to all three axis is the origin?

Comment: .. or *almost* any line - it just shuold not be parallel to einther of the three planes. For example, the points $(1,1,0)\in O_{xy}$, $(2,0,1)\in O_{xz}$, and $(0,2,-1)\in O_{yz}$ are collinear.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: what is the 
"it" that shouldn't be parallel to either of the 3 planes?

Comment: Why do we use a big O before writing $_{xy}$ in small case?

Comment: What set is the point (1,1,0) an element of? is the point (1,1,0), an element of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCdSk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the lines that are not parallel to a coordinate plane intersect all the three coordinate planes.

In the figure you can see the line that passes thorough the points $A=(2,1,0)$ and $ B=(0,2,1)$, that has equation $(x,y,z)=t(2,-1,-1)+(0,2,1)$ and intesects the plane $y=0$ at $C=(4,0,-1)$.

[image]